# Monochromatic solution to $x + qy = z$ for $q \in \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

I want to find a proof that for any given $r \in \mathbb{N}$ and $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ every $r$-coloring of the integers shows a monochromatic solution for $x + qy = z$.

I am aware that if the equation is $x + y = z$ we have Shur's Theorem and if $x + y = 2z$ the problem is equivalent to finding a monochromatic arithmetic progression of length 3 $\{x, x + d, x + 2d\}$ (and we can prove it finding a necessary amount of monochromatic pairs of numbers with the same sum).

This problem is in a book I'm studying and I was trying to adapt the proof for the other problem involving $x+y = 2z$ (even though the former doesn't try to find arithmetic progressions) but couldn't solve it yet.
I also thought about trying to use some probabilistic argument; don't know if it is of any use here.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: The sledgehammer approach is using Rado's theorem, but I guess you are looking for a more elementary approach

Comment: Actually Rado's theorem would be a fine path for me! Since it works with integer coefficients maybe we have to do something like:

Let $q = a/b$, for $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

$$x + qy = z$$

$$xb + ay - bz = 0$$ 

And since $(b, a, -b)$ satisfies the columns condition we have a monochromatic solution $\{x, y, z\}$.

If it checks out and you want to leave the comment as an answer I would accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $q=a/b$ and multiplying by $b$ your equation is equivalent to the integer coefficients equation $bx+ay-bz=0$, which is partition regular by Rado's theorem since the coefficents of $x$ and $z$ sum to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Shur's theorem states that there is always a + y = b, so there is always (aq) + qy = (bq), let x = aq and z = bq, so there is always x + qy = z

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If we are given that $\{a, y, b\}$ is monochromatic, it isn't guaranteed that $(aq)$ and $(bq)$ have the same color of $a$ and $b$, right?

Also $(aq)$ and $(bq)$ are not necessarily integers, if I'm not missing something.